# Passing DropDownList SelectedValue to SQL Query throws Input String was not in a Correct Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm working on an ASP.NET webforms page that queries the database for a list of entries in the Study table.  These entries are to be passed into the dropdownlist.  When a study is selected from the dropdownlist, the studyID is to be passed to the GetResponses method to retrieve associated data from a stored procedure.

I receive `Input String was not in a Correct Format` with the following snippets:

```
 private DataTable LoadStudies(int iStudyID )
{
    ddlStudies.Items.Clear();
    ddlStudies.SelectedValue = "0";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (PROTOTYPING db = new PROTOTYPING(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        var query = (from d in db.Studies
            where d.StudyStatus == 0 //Closed...
            orderby d.StudyName
            select new
            {
                d.StudyName,
                d.StudyID,
            });
        if (query.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var a in query)
            {
                ddlStudies.Items.Add(new ListItem(a.StudyID.ToString()));
            }
        }

        dt.Dispose();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

The error is thrown on the Page_Load which is currently written as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iUserID = 0;

    if (Session["UserID"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    iUserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
    int iRole = 0;
    iRole = Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoleID"]);

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        LoadStudies(Convert.ToInt32(ddlStudies.SelectedValue));
        GetResponses(Convert.ToInt32(ddlStudies.SelectedValue));

        ddlStudies.DataSource = LoadStudies(Convert.ToInt32(ddlStudies.SelectedValue));
        ddlStudies.DataTextField = "StudyName";
        ddlStudies.DataValueField = "StudyID";
        ddlStudies.DataBind();
    }
}
```

How do I resolve the error, which is thrown when assigning the dropdownlist's DataSource to the LoadStudies method?

Comment: have you check by debugging what is value for `ddlStudies.SelectedValue`?

Comment: Where is iStudyID used in LoadStudies?

Comment: Do you know Visual Studio has a debugger to debug such scenarios? Debug and find out the offending value yourself. Also, try using `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: `ddlStudies.SelectedValue` is not a valid integer value `0`,`1`,`2` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ddlStudies.SelectedValue` is not a valid integer value `0`,`1`,`2` etc.

I would wager a guess it's an empty string. `Convert.ToInt32("")`, which will throw the exception you are experiencing.

Interestingly `Convert.ToInt32(null)` will return a zero.

> **Try** 
>   `Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddlStudies.SelectedValue) ? null : ddlStudies.SelectedValue)`

Comment: This resolved the error in my question.  Unfortunately, a new NullReferenceError is thrown on  a getDataTable function.  Will post in separate question.  Thanks!

Comment: ok, best to start a new question, as the null reference is a follow on problem... good luck, perhaps spend some time reading the debugger manual or find a debugging tips video on pluralsight... there must be one.